# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Tags: php

I can't understand why eval doesn't work on this string.

This works:

```
eval(base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw=='));
```

This doesn't:

```
$test= "base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw==');";
eval($test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order of operations is killing you. the two examples are not alike in the least.

```
eval(base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw=='));
```

is more like

```
$test = base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw==');
eval($test);
```

however the second sample has base64_decode parse out the string 'phpinfo();' inside of the eval. and does nothing with that string afterwords.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If I store the eval($test) in a second variable, and then echo that variable. there is nothing.

Comment: eval returns null unless the string that went into eval used return.

Comment: What do you mean used return?

Comment: $test = "return base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw==');";
    $output = eval($test);
    echo $output;

Answer (score 0):

```
$test= base64_decode('cGhwaW5mbygpOw==');
eval($test);
```

This will.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: No, I need to assign the variable as a string....

Comment: Why? Do you need to? Also you should avoid using eval.

Comment: Because I am creating a list of usages to understand the technical aspects of php, good bad or otherwise.